# Responses to "Schön, dich wiederzusehen"

Tags: usage

A friend who you haven't met in a long time says to you

> Schön, dich wiederzusehen.

How do you respond? I imagine the most common response would be

> Gleichfalls.

Would

> Dich auch.

be grammatically correct? Also, what are some other suggestions?

Comment: *Gleichfalls* funktioniert; *Dich auch* ist nicht üblich.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ich freue mich auch, dich wiederzusehen.

In my opinion the very short answers ("Gleichfalls", "Dich auch") tend to be misunderstood or to be not as polite as you want to be.

Answer (score 1):

What I like in situations like this is a simple

```
Die Freude | Das Vergnügen ist ganz meinerseits.
```

Which would translate to "The pleasure is all mine"

Comment: I prefer [hellcode's answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/18342/5999); your suggestion may be suitable for writing, but using words such as *Vergnügen* or in particular *meinerseits* would sound extremely overblown in spoken German.

Answer (score 0):

"Es ist mir immer eine Freude".
-Works well as polite/casual response. 
"Dich auch". 
-Is OK (in conversation), but would be interpreted as a rather cold response, if that's your intention.

Comment: Combine it with a grin!

Comment: Was ist falsch an "Dich auch"? Aber "Es ist mir immer eine Freude" klingt zu formal für jeglichen Anlass. Das kann man nur ironisch verwenden.

Comment: @Kay,  just looked up 'Dich auch' as a response. Actually it's grammatically incorrect. In any case, hellcode's answer is appropriate.

Comment: @user11298 could you elaborare as to why it is incorrect?